# QGIS 3.0.2 NNJoin doesn't complete. Crashes when close status bar

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, nearest-neighbor

I have run a large spatial point to polygon join of 2 million points to 657 polygons. I used NNJoin so that the closest polygon will be assigned to a point if the point does not lie within one.
The process ran for around 6 hours. The status bar showed 100%, but no 'finished' message or result output file was added to QGIS or can be found in my directory.
If I close the status bar on QGIS, I get a Python error "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted.
Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log a bug report in the tracker for the plugin:

https://github.com/havatv/qgisnnjoinplugin/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: Thanks, I have done that now. Seems to work fine for smaller files.

Comment: The issue can be found on https://github.com/havatv/qgisnnjoinplugin/issues/17. It was fixed 15 May (it was a problem with the progress bar).